# Generate multiple css classes for react component with Emoiton Js

Tags: reactjs, emotion

I had to use react-phone-input-2 package in my GatsbyJs project with Emotion JS. It can receive multiple classNames. 
if i pass some className to  like this:

```
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2"
<PhoneInput
inputClass={css`font-size: 24px;`}
```

I'll get the next error:

```
<input class="You have tried to stringify object returned from `css` function. It isn't supposed to be used directly (e.g. as value of the `className` prop), but rather handed to emotion so it can handle it (e.g. as value of `css` prop). form-control" id="phone-form-control" placeholder="1 (702) 123-4567" type="tel" value="+1">
```

The one thing that worked for me is using ClassNames from

```
import { ClassNames } from "@emotion/core"

const phoneNumStyles = `font-size: 24px !important;`
 const errorBorder = `border: 1px solid #FF4757 !important;`

 <ClassNames>
 {({ css }) => (
 <PhoneInput
 inputClass={
 props.errors.phone &&
 props.touched["phone-form-control"]
 ? css([phoneNumStyles, errorBorder])
 : css(phoneNumStyles)
 }
```

But the problem there was that i had to use `!important` to give weight for styles i declared; Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Have you tried passing a simple object: `inputClass={{fontSize: "24px"}}`?

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to use Objects, i have to use css :hover, media queries etc. There's no way to define it in single object

Comment: Emotion JS provides Object Styles ```css={{
      color: 'darkorchid',
      '@media(min-width: 420px)': {
        color: 'orange'
      }
    }}``` but it didn't work in my code